# Jest: .toThrow matcher does not pass test on Error

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to test invalid Inputs of a function and expect the function to throw 
on that inputs. However the test does not pass but the function still throws the error. Im kind of a beginner with jest so I dont know why that happens.

**My function looks like this:**

```js
export class MyClass{
 static theFunction(tokens){
        let result = [];
        if (typeof tokens[0] === "string") {
            return tokens;
        } else {
            try {
                for(let token of tokens){
                    result.push(token.text);
                }
                return result;
            } catch (e) {
                throw new Error(e); //also tried throw e; and no try/catch aswell
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

**Test.js:**

```js
import {MyClass} from './MyClass'
describe('Test the MyClass:', () => {
    test('invalid inputs for thefunction()',  () => {
        expect(MyClass.theFunction(0)).toThrow(/*'TypeError: tokens is not iterable'*/); 
        //Tried with and without the Error Message
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your function in an anonymous function so that Jest can catch the error:

```js
describe('Test the MyClass:', () => {
    test('invalid inputs for thefunction()',  () => {
        expect( () => { MyClass.theFunction(0) } ).toThrow();
    });
});
```

You might want to read the section about [toThrow() in the Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) and also check the [implementation in the Jest project](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/ee2bea16a9f401581a884d9faa0951b552a86fe4/packages/expect/src/toThrowMatchers.ts#L102) on Github.

Comment: Thank you. That works. I read the documentation, but I was surprized that Jest doesnt treat functions as functions. But thank you again. Now know^^.